# Java Process thread is running parallel, when command is executed directly in Java

Tags: java, batch-file, java-process-runtime

When I am running the batch command `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > nul` (waits 5 seconds) in Java "directly":

```
public class Test {
          public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    
              Process testProcess =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > nul");
              testProcess.waitFor();
              System.out.println("foo");
          }
}
```

the String `"foo"`
prints out instant and not after 5 seconds, even the `.waitFor()` method should make the thread wait, until the process is finished.

But when I change  `testProcess` to  `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Users/Desktop/test.bat")` to execute a Batch file, which has only the command `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > nul` inside it, the `.waitFor()`method waits until the process is finished. So that the `"foo"` is printed after 5 seconds.

Why is that so?

---

**EDIT:**

I needed to remove `> nul` (see @Generous Badger 's comment)

Comment: Have you checked the return value of `waitFor`? The `>` is not interpreted by `Runtime.exec()`, handling redirects like that is usually done by a shell and no shell is involved here. Try to remove the `> nul` and use `ProcessBuilder.redirectOutput()` to output redirect the output to wherever you want instead.

Comment: Ah yeah thanks, I needed to remove the `> nul`, then it works without `ProcessBuilder` or batch file

Comment: `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5` waits for **4** seconds (5 attempts with 4 pause intervals of a second each)!

Comment: If for some reason you needed some redirection you would have to explicitly invoke the Command Interpreter by `cmd /C ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > nul`…